# Why was the question about thermistors migrated?

Tags: discussion, scope, migration

[This question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/244366/how-do-i-tell-if-my-thermistors-are-10k-or-100k) was migrated to electronics.SE. To me the migration makes no sense:

- The question deals with a problem that is relevant to the users of this site
- This site can provide a more specialized answer than electronics.SE can provide: you don't just need to know whether it's a 10k or 100k thermistor, but also figure out the correct thermistor table in your firmware. electronics.SE does not have knowledge of 3D printer firmware, which is the issue underlying this question.

Obviously there's some overlap between Arduino/Electronics/3D printing, but what determines whether a question should be migrated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question was migrated because the specific question of "*How do I tell if my Thermistors are 10k or 100k?*" is going to be best answered by users of Electrical Engineering SE. This also provides the SE network with more appropriate traffic based on the question at hand.

However, if the question of "*How can I change the thermistors settings in Marlin firmware?*" were to arise, then the question would be best suited here on 3D Printing. It might help both SE sites by providing links to each other's relevant questions for future users to reference.

If the question was something like "*How can I wire a hotend?*", this would be more appropriate here on 3D Printing SE as users in Electrical Engineering SE may not know as much about the topic compared to users in 3D Printing. This may be a poor example, but the idea is that there is strict correlation between *hotends* and 3D printing, whereas identifying thermistors is not a specific topic to just 3D printing.

**Update**

After reading a few posts on SE meta, [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) leads me to agree with you that this particular question may not have needed to be migrated. However, it exposes an important question of how we want to proceed with questions like this in the future? How far down the rabbit hole do we want to allow this site to go in this topic? I'd recommend others pitch in recommendations in answers here on what would be the appropriate topic in this case that can be applied to our [On-Topic](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page so that it may be amended.

Comment: I believe that a question should only be migrated if it is **off-topic** for the site where it is being migrated from. I am sure it was *also* suitable for electrical engineering, but that is secondary to the question of whether it is appropriate for this site. I don't think the question was off-topic, as determining what kind of thermistor your printer has is something you might run into while 3D printing. We could have answered the question from a 3D printing perspective, whereas an answer from an electrical engineering perspective might not be what the user was looking for.

Comment: @TomvanderZanden I've updated my response above. My perspective was that the question was almost entirely related to EE SE and only remotely related to 3DP SE. However I agree that this is a grey area currently, so its subjective. I'll keep this post in mind in the future and refrain from migrations on this subject until the community deems it on/off topic. I don't think the post shows it anymore, but I did ask the OP if they felt it appropriate to migrate specifically to EE SE. Hence the comment "That's true. Can that be done by someone with more rep?". Thank you for bringing this topic up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the question should be migrated. For EE.SE, the question is just stupidly obvious. Even a fairly inexperienced lab tech. would know how to go about answering that question. It really isn't an electronic engineering question at all.

Here, the answer (assuming the question is actually the question that the user needed to ask) would be 'buy the cheapest meter you can find', or 'buy both, you might not make much use of a cheap meter anyway'. Context makes a big difference.